Which LaTeX software to use transfer my code of thesis from Notepad to LATEX software
I am using Notepad to write my master thesis in code of LaTeX. I was using overleaf but it doesn't allows me to paste the code from Notepad to overleaf.
So, which software can I use to paste my code from Notepad in it?
Thank  you very much

What exactly do you mean by "does not allow me to paste the code from notepad to overleaf"? Last time I tried I could paste from everywhere. So please provide more details

You can also save the file and upload it to Overleaf.

@DavidCarlisle I am new to overleaf. I don't know any better.
